# How to sort dates in table using vue.js

Tags: javascript, sorting, date, html-table, vue.js

My table is based on the **Grid Component Example** in Vue.js' website

I'm having problem with sorting dates inside the table.  I get all the table data from server side as JSON. So in the codes provided, I just mocked the data in **var mockDataFromServerSide**.

Here is the code: https://jsfiddle.net/5w1wzhvw/3/

HTML file:

```
<!-- component template -->
<script type="text/x-template" id="grid-template">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th v-for="key in columns"
          v-on:click="sortBy(key)"
          :class="{active: sortKey == key}">
          {{key | capitalize}}
          <span class="arrow"
            :class="sortOrders[key] > 0 ? 'asc' : 'dsc'">
          </span>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="
        entry in data
        | filterBy filterKey
        | orderBy sortKey sortOrders[sortKey]">
        <td v-for="key in columns">
          {{entry[key]}}
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</script>

<!-- demo root element -->
<div id="demo">
  <form id="search">
    Search <input name="query" v-model="searchQuery">
  </form>
  <demo-grid
    :filter-key="searchQuery">
  </demo-grid>
</div>
```

Js file:

```
var gridColumns = ['name', 'date'];
var mockDataFromServerSide = [
      { name: 'Chuck Norris', date: "01 Dec 2016" },
      { name: 'Bruce Lee', date: "23 Apr 2005" },
      { name: 'Jackie C', date: "30 Jan 2012" },
      { name: 'Jet Li', date: "20 Apr 2006" }
    ];
// register the grid component
Vue.component('demo-grid', {
  template: '#grid-template',
  props: {
        filterKey: String
  },
  data: function () {
    var sortOrders = {}
    gridColumns.forEach(function (key) {
      sortOrders[key] = 1
    })
    return {
      sortKey: '',
      sortOrders: sortOrders,
      columns: gridColumns,
      data: mockDataFromServerSide
    }
  },
  methods: {
    sortBy: function (key) {
      this.sortKey = key
      this.sortOrders[key] = this.sortOrders[key] * -1
    }
  }
})

// bootstrap the demo
var demo = new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data: {
    searchQuery: ''
  }
})
```

I also tried to add a filter to the date. The sort is correct but the displayed dates are shown as "**Thu Apr 02 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (China Standard Time)**". I want the dates to be displayed as **02 Apr 2016**.

Added filter Code: https://jsfiddle.net/kr1m5de5/1/

HTML file (added filter):

```
<!-- component template -->
<script type="text/x-template" id="grid-template">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th v-for="key in columns"
          v-on:click="sortBy(key)"
          :class="{active: sortKey == key}">
          {{key | capitalize}}
          <span class="arrow"
            :class="sortOrders[key] > 0 ? 'asc' : 'dsc'">
          </span>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="
        entry in data
        | filterBy filterKey
        | orderBy sortKey sortOrders[sortKey]
        | datesFilter">
        <td v-for="key in columns">
          {{entry[key]}}
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</script>

<!-- demo root element -->
<div id="demo">
  <form id="search">
    Search <input name="query" v-model="searchQuery">
  </form>
  <demo-grid
    :filter-key="searchQuery">
  </demo-grid>
</div>
```

JS file (added filter):

```
var gridColumns = ['name', 'date'];

var mockDataFromServerSide = [
      { name: 'Chuck Norris', date: "01 Dec 2016" },
      { name: 'Bruce Lee', date: "23 Apr 2005" },
      { name: 'Jackie C', date: "30 Jan 2012" },
      { name: 'Jet Li', date: "20 Apr 2006" }
    ];
// register the grid component
Vue.component('demo-grid', {
  template: '#grid-template',
  props: {
        filterKey: String
  },
  filters: {
    datesFilter: function (data) {
      data.forEach(function (row) {
        row.date = new Date(row.date);
      });
      return data;
        }
    },
  data: function () {
    var sortOrders = {}
    gridColumns.forEach(function (key) {
      sortOrders[key] = 1
    })
    return {
      sortKey: '',
      sortOrders: sortOrders,
      columns: gridColumns,
      data: mockDataFromServerSide
    }
  },
  methods: {
    sortBy: function (key) {
      this.sortKey = key
      this.sortOrders[key] = this.sortOrders[key] * -1
    }
  }
})

// bootstrap the demo
var demo = new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data: {
    searchQuery: ''
  }
})
```

Please let me know how to fix it or if there is a better way to do it.

Comment: I was thinking about adding as special sortFunction for the date column and use either attributes or a hidden column inside `mockDataFromServerSide` but i could not solve it yet.

Comment: im so embarrassed i used your jsfiddle as a starting point for what i just answered, like a year and a half ago... i did not even had a stackoverflow account back then, you probably don't even need this anymore :'(

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by making a `TableHeader` component it says semantic cause i used semantic-ui... sorry for the spanglish in the code, must of 'em are cognates anyway. Also, this code is working, but if you see improvements to the code/answer let me know please!

As you can see, i really don't sort at front... i make a new request with the sorted items.

```js
<template>
    <th @click="cycleSort(sth, $event)">
        <span><span>{{ sth.texto }}&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><i class="icon" :class="sth.icon"></i><sub v-if="sth.posicion > 0"><small>{{ sth.posicion }}</small></sub></span>
    </th>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: "SemanticTableHeader",
  props: {
      sth : {
          type : Object,
          default: () => {}
      },
      sths : {
          type : Array,
          default: () => { return [] }
      },
      filtrosOrder : {
          type : Array,
          default: () => { return [] }
      },
      isSearching : {
          type : Boolean,
          required : true
      }
  },
  methods: {
      cycleSort(sth, event) {

          if(this.isSearching == true){
              return false;
          }

          switch (sth.direction) {
              case null:
              sth.direction = 'asc';
              sth.icon = 'sort ascending';
              break;

              case 'asc':
              sth.direction = 'desc';
              sth.icon = 'sort descending';
              break;

              case 'desc':
              sth.direction = null;
              sth.icon = 'sort disabled';
              break;

              default:
              sth.direction = null;
              sth.icon = 'sort disabled';
          }

        this.manejaCambioHeader(sth);

      },
      manejaCambioHeader: _.debounce(function (sth) {
          var self = this;

          console.log(this.filtrosOrder);

          let auxUser = _.find(this.filtrosOrder, function(o) { return o.id == sth.id; });

          if( auxUser != null ){

              auxUser.direction = sth.direction;

              if(auxUser.direction == null){
                  for (var i=0 ; i < this.filtrosOrder.length ; i++){
                      if (this.filtrosOrder[i].id === auxUser.id) {

                          let auxSths =  _.find(self.sths, function(o) { return o.id == sth.id; });
                          auxSths.posicion = 0;

                          this.filtrosOrder.splice(i, 1);
                      }
                  }
              }
          }else{
              this.filtrosOrder.push({ id: sth.id, direction: sth.direction });
          }

          for (var i=0 ; i < self.filtrosOrder.length; i++){
              let auxSths =  _.find(this.sths, function(o) { return o.id == self.filtrosOrder[i].id; });

              auxSths.posicion = i + 1;
          }

          console.log(this.filtrosOrder);

          this.$emit('sortHeaderChanged', sth);

    }, 400),
  },
}
</script>
<style lang="css" scoped>
th span{
    cursor: pointer !important;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* iOS Safari */
    -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari */
    -khtml-user-select: none; /* Konqueror HTML */
    -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
    -ms-user-select: none; /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
    user-select: none; /* Non-prefixed version, currently supported by Chrome and Opera */
}

i.icon{
    margin: 0em -0.2em 0em 0em;
}
</style>
```

In my Index views i just load the component and use it like this

```js
<template>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <semantic-table-header v-for="sth in sths" :key="sth.key"
                :sth="sth"
                :sths="sths"
                :isSearching="isSearching"
                :filtrosOrder="filtros.orderBy"
                @sortHeaderChanged="fetchIndex"
                ></semantic-table-header>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr v-for="contact in contacts" :key="contact.key" :class="[contact.justAdded ? 'justAdded' : '']">
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</template>

export default {
    name: "ContactsIndex",
    data:() => ({
        filtros:{
            orderBy:[
                {   id: 'nombre',   direction: 'asc'    } // orderBy is calculated through the headers component
            ]
        },
        sths:[
            {   id: 'nombre',       texto: 'Nombre',                icon: 'sort ascending',     direction: 'asc',   posicion: 1 },
            {   id: 'telefonos',    texto: 'Teléfono(s)',           icon: 'sort disabled',      direction: null,    posicion: 0 },
            {   id: 'emails',       texto: 'Correo Electrónico(s)', icon: 'sort disabled',      direction: null,    posicion: 0 },
            {   id: 'estatus',      texto: 'Estatus',               icon: 'sort disabled',      direction: null,    posicion: 0 }
        ],
        contacts: [],
    }),
    created() {
        this.fetchIndex();
    },
    methods: {
        resetFilters() {
            // this function is to reset filters and headers
            Object.assign(this.$data.filtros, this.$options.data().filtros);
            this.$data.sths =  this.$options.data().sths;
            this.fetchIndex();
        },
        fetchIndex() {
            let self = this;

            // this is a wrapper i made for an axios post call you can replace it with a normal call
            singleIndexRequest('/api/v1/contacts/index', self).then(response => {
                self.contacts = response.data.contacts;
            });
        },
    }
}
```